# How to calculate EPS q/q in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am new in pine script and I would like to calculate EPS q/q (for example, Q42020/Q42019) of one stock and print the result percentage wise.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To get financial data, use the function `financial`. For more information about what data you can get, read the [article](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/ED5BAHMn/?solution=43000564727)